# Memcached and virtual memory

Tags: memcached, virtual-memory

According to [this thread](http://apartm.net/hackernews/index.php?id=3519145) (not very reliable, I know) memcached does not use the disk, not even **virtual memory**.

My questions are:

1. Is this true?
2. If so, how does memcached ensures that the memory he gets assigned **never overflows** to disk?

Comment: As the linked thread makes clear, the question was based on a misunderstanding. Virtual memory is not the same as paging or swapping. Notice it says: "I assume you actually mean 'does memcached not page data out to disk'"

Answer (score 4):

`memcached` avoids going to swap through two mechanisms:

1. Informing the system administrators that the machines should never go to swap. This allows the admins to maybe not configure swap space for the machine (seems like a bad idea to me) or configure the memory limits of the running applications to ensure that nothing ever goes into swap. (Not just `memcached`, but *all* applications.)
2. The `mlockall(2)` system call can be used (`-k`) to ensure that *all* the process's memory is always locked in memory. This is mediated via the `setrlimit(2)` `RLIMIT_MEMLOCK` control, so admins would need to modify e.g. `/etc/security/limits.conf` to allow the `memcached` user account to lock a lot more memory than is normal. (Locked memory is mediated to prevent untrusted user accounts from starving the rest of the system of free memory.)

Both these steps are fair *assuming* the point of the machine is to run `memcached` and perhaps very little else. This is often a fair assumption, as larger deployments will dedicate several (or many) machines to `memcached`.

Answer (score 1):

You configure memcached to use a fixed amount of memory. When that memory is full memcached just deletes old data to stay under the limit. It is that simple.

Comment: memcached *does* use virtual memory, but it does not (intentionally) page to disk. However, this is not the choice of memcached. the OS decides when and what to page. Fortunately, if the memory limit is not set too high, there is never memory pressure on the system, so the OS does not need to page out data.

Comment: And because memcached is a cache, not a database, it can just delete your data whenever it thinks it needs to.

Comment: Your answer does not explain what happens if memory pressure is high

Comment: @checat I think I do say that. It deletes data.